# Почему div inline-block выпадает при добавлении в него текста

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите4 сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что если добавляю в sec1 или sec2 текст, то див выпадает вниз. Если добавить в оба, они остаются на местк. Почему так происходит?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"/>.
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section1">
            <span>123</span>
        </div>
        <div class="section2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
section{
    background-color: #c77700;
}
```

```
.section1{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #2b4554;
}

.section2{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #0f834d;
}
```

Comment: Потому что надо использовать флексы а не инлайн блоки из 90х

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что inline-block'ам нужно ещё вертикальное выравнивание задавать, чтоб они не разъезжались:

```css
section{
    background-color: #c77700;
}
.section1{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #2b4554;
}

.section2{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #0f834d;
}
.section1, .section2{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section1">
            <span>123</span>
        </div>
        <div class="section2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А почему так происходит?

Comment: @ensom, потому что по умолчанию у inline-block установлено vertical-align: baseline. Когда Вы в один инлайновый блок добавляете текст, он выстраивается в эту базовую линию, а сам блок, соответственно, съезжает.

Comment: Большое спасибо!